# Update UITableViewCell from BaseViewModel class

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm trying to update a TableViewCell with my stringData from this method in my BaseViewModel class, the stringData is recovered from a socket:

```
func getSocketData(stringData: String) {
        if let jsonData = stringData.data(using: .utf8) {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let quotationNew = try decoder.decode(Quotation.self, from: jsonData)
                if self.quotations != nil {
                    for quo in self.quotations! where quo.ticker == quotationNew.ticker {

                        let res = (quotationNew.previousPrice?.toInt() ?? 0) - (quo.previousPrice?.toInt() ?? 0)
                        let model = buildQuotationModel(quotationNew)                        
                        model.dateSocket = quotationNew.date
                        model.sign = self.comparePrice(newPrice: quotationNew.last, variation: Double(res), ticker: quotationNew.ticker!)

                        quo.buyAmount = quotationNew.buyAmount
                        quo.buyPrice = quotationNew.buyPrice
                        quo.volume = quotationNew.volume
                        quo.date = quotationNew.date
                        quo.sellAmount = quotationNew.sellAmount
                        quo.sellPrice = quotationNew.sellPrice
                        quo.minQuotation = quotationNew.minQuotation
                        quo.maxQuotation = quotationNew.maxQuotation
                        quo.previousPrice = quotationNew.previousPrice
                        quo.timestamp = quotationNew.timestamp

                        let index = self.quotations?.index(of: quo)
                        delegate.updateConstraints()
                        self.reloadRow?(model, index!)                        
                        break
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            print(error.debugDescription, " - Error when converting string to Data")
        }
    }
```

This is my QuotationCell class, where I have to update my data:

```
func drawCell(_ tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: QuotationCell = tableView.dequeue(for: indexPath)
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.tickerLabel.text = bonusIdentifier
        cell.quotationLabel.text = lastQuotation
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = description
        cell.dateLabel.text = "\("last_update".localized) \(date ?? "")"
        cell.variationContainer.backgroundColor = variationColor
        cell.term = term ?? "-"
        cell.hideLeftIcon = hideLeftIcon
        cell.isInWatchlist = isInWatchlist
        cell.isAbsoluteVariation = isAbsoluteVariation
        cell.variationLabel.text = (isAbsoluteVariation ? absoluteVariationValue : percentageVariationValue) ?? "-"
        cell.variationContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = absoluteVariation != nil
        cell.onTappedVariation = onTappedVariation
        cell.addBottomBorder(with: .lightBlueGrey, andWidth: 0.5)
        applyEffect(cell)
        return cell
    }
```

I have tried with this delegate and all these methods, but doesn't work for me

```
func updateConstraints() {
        self.tableView.updateConstraints()
        self.tableView.updateFocusIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The model shouldn't delegate to the cell.  Changes to your model should be observed by your view controller (delegation is once pattern you can use for that). The view controller can then take an appropriate action (such as reloading a row or updating a cell). A completion handler closure might be a better choice for the `getSocketData` function than delegation.